# Toggle animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, toggle

I have a toggle Javascript in my code which shows and hides two different divs when clicking on links in the html code:

```
function toggleAbout() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleAbout");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayAbout");
    var eleContatti = document.getElementById("toggleContatti");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "About";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "About";
        eleContatti.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function toggleContatti() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleContatti");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayContatti");
    var eleAbout = document.getElementById("toggleAbout");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        eleAbout.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

However I want to animate the divs, making them scroll from top to bottom slowly, and not showing them completely directly when the links are clicked. I have seen many examples with toggle animation but don't know how to integrate them in the code I already have. I've never worked with Javascript but need this for a website, how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? The first hit on googling `JavaScrip animate` is a link to the [jQuery API](http://api.jQuery.com/animate), the second is to [a tutorial](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/). I suggest you take a look there, first...

Comment: Use specially [jquery animations](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Check this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025074/jquery-animate-hide-and-show

Answer (score 0):

I too suggest using JQuery, but it can be done with javascript too. What you need to do is change the css property **gradually** with **timeouts/intervals**. JQuery makes this easy for you.

```
$('#selector').animate({'height':'100px'})
```

for example will gradually increase/decrease height of element with id selector till it reaches 100 px. This gives the effect of animation.

For slides and fades u can change position and opacity respectively.

In **Javascript** you have to use **Intervals**.