# Jquery hide one div and apply smooth transition effect on other divs to reorder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have list of div and click on that div it show result of another div Toggle, there is close options for that also. my need is close on that div i need effect of ordering with smooth transition effect.

Comment: you need show your research effort. What have you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025074/jquery-animate-hide-and-show can it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer...
This is jQuery plugin...
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

You can put it together with your Toggle one, if you want it to.