# How do I create animation on hide/show?

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .overlay::after
     {
           position: fixed;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           width: 100%;
           content: "";
           z-index: -1;
           height: 100%;
           transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
           opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .popup::before
        {
           content: "";
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           width: 100%;. 
           height: 100%;
           z-index: -1;
           transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
```

This is my overlay class. I display this div as mask for all the popups. But the problem is it doesn't show me any animations even though I have transition property. I want to bring it left to right end. I can do this by giving negative left while hidden and positive left while shown. Is there any way to achieve this without having negative left. Any suggestions??

Comment: check this link
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025074/jquery-animate-hide-and-show     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638990/jquery-show-and-hide-div-on-mouse-click-animate

Comment: Is there any possibility to achieve without jquer

Comment: i think u want to using css ?

Comment: I want to achieve this using Css.

Comment: u can use keyframe like this link http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1

Answer (score 1):

pure css could be

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: left .3s ease
}
menu li{padding: 10px 14px}
input:checked + menu{
  left: 0
}
label{cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<label for=toogleMenu >Click to toggle the Menu </label>
<input type=checkbox id=toogleMenu hidden />
<menu>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Work</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>Help</li>
</menu>
```

Using transform

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  transition: transform .3s ease
}
menu li{padding: 10px 14px}
input:checked + menu{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
label{cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<label for=toogleMenu >Click to toggle the Menu </label>
<input type=checkbox id=toogleMenu hidden />
<menu>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Work</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>Help</li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks Tambo. So I must use negative left to achieve this transition effect with CSS..

Comment: what what what again please

Comment: I am using pseudo classes. Not separate class. If i apply this property to pseudo class, it ll move popup also.